# Speeding up ndarray.argmax over an axis with only a few elements

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I'm trying to speed up the performance of `ndarray.argmax()` when the axis it is iterating over only has a few elements (I'd also like to improve the performance of `ndarray.max()` but will settle for `argmax()` if that is all that is possible). The other dimensions of the array have many elements.

Here is an example:

```
from numpy import *
r = random.rand(128,128,128,2)
o = empty(shape(r[...,0]), dtype=int)

## numpy .argmax()
r.argmax(axis=3, out=o)

## Using logic arguments
less(r[...,0], r[...,1], out=o)
```

The second version is about twice as fast in this example on my computer. I have two question: 1. Is there a way to speed this up further? and 2. Can this approach be extended to an axis with 3 to 5 elements while still maintaining the performance advantage?

Answer (score 0):

Well,

```
o = r[...,0] < r[...,1]
```

is faster than both (on my system).

As for your second question, I'm not sure what output you want in the case of comparing more than 2 values across your third axis. Can you clarify with an example? `argmax` and `less` do different things and it's only because your last axis has dimension 2 that you get the same result here. This solution would replace `less` for a simple `True`/`False` comparison of the values, but `argmax` actually finds the index of the maximum.

Comment: In my example, I use `less` to replace `argmax`. You can theoretically use multiple logical statements (like `less`) to identify the `argmax` for a dimension with 3 or more elements. I'm interested if this approach has been used (in numpy or another high-performance package) to achieve a performance boost when only dealing with a few elements.

Comment: also, `o = r[...,0] < r[...,1]` isn't actually faster when you consider the type conversion that needs to happen. What you wrote is creating a new bool array (which would need to be converted to an int array later). To keep the existing array and force the conversion similar to my example, you'd need to do `o[:] = r[...,0] < r[...,1]` which is just a touch slower on my machine.